# Lattice-based cryptosystems for blockchain/ledger?

Tags: lattice-crypto

Are there lattice-based cryptosystems based i.e., SIS (Short Integer Solutions) and LWE (Learning with Errors) blockchain solutions for a post quantum world?

Has the Unique Shortest Vector Problem (SVP) been solved?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question, could you rephrase it?

Comment: `Has the Unique Shortest Vector Problem (SVP) been solved?` Appears to be a separate question altogether

Answer (score 1):

> Are there [...] blockchain solutions for a post quantum world?

Quantum Computing and related algorithms are no threat to the current protocol of Bitcoin (and most other blockchain systems I am familiar with) at all. Indeed, Shor's algorithm can solve the Discrete Logarithm Problem (DLP) efficiently, and [a modified version](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301141) exists for the elliptic curve analogue (ECDLP). Blockchain systems in their conventional form are based on

- *preimage and collision resistance of the employed hash functions* for most functions, including transaction IDs, block IDs, and the Proof-of-Work (PoW) scheme in mining
- *hardness of DLP/ECDLP* for security of transaction signatures and user addresses (so that private keys can not be found)

At the current state of research, most consider hash functions quantum resistant due to their lack of mathematical structure. As mentioned, (EC)DLP is not resistant.

**However**, if user addresses are never re-used then this is irrelevant, since an attacker will only learn a users clean (i.e. non-hashed) public key once a transaction is signed in the name of said user address/public key. As long as the hash function (e.g. SHA-256) is preimage-resistant, an attacker has nothing to apply Shor's algorithm on.
So there is no pressing need for alternatives yet.

Nonetheless, lattice-based crypto is a proposal that comes up once in a while - to my knowledge no actual blockchain implementation exists as of today. As for the Shortest Vector Problem (SVP): the most efficient known algorithms are mentioned [in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Shortest_vector_problem_(SVP)).

Comment: I am not an expert, but I highly doubt that bitcoin is secure if the signature scheme used for transactions is broken. After sending bitcoins to someone, the sender knows the public key of the receiver. If the scheme is broken, he could then forge a transaction valid under that public key and transfer the money back to his accounts. Or no?

Comment: @mti well this is less on-topic for crypto SE but rather a protocol design decision (with security considerations). yes, someone can forge the signature for the attacked address. But as I wrote, this does not matter if addresses are used only once. You see, each transaction empties the address and spends all coins: the desired amount goes to the destination, the rest is spend as "change" back to an address controlled by the sender. So if you always change your address an attacker can sign in the name of an address which has balance 0.

Comment: "he could then forge a transaction valid under that public key and transfer the money back to his accounts" no, reversing transactions is not possible in the network.

Comment: If the signature scheme is broken, then one can create signatures valid with a given public wallet key without knowing the corresponding secret transaction key. This means, however, that one can spend the coins associated with the corresponding wallet. It seems impossible to maintain coin ownership in such a setting!

Comment: @mti each "public wallet key" is essentially the hashed public key of a generated elliptic-curve key pair. In the setting we discuss (quantum computer adversary), an attacker can find out private keys to given public keys. But a user's public key only becomes known to the network when it is used to spend coins for the first time - before that, only the hashed Base58 encoded version is known. As I said in my answer: "As long as the hash function (e.g. SHA-256) is preimage-resistant, an attacker has nothing to apply Shor's algorithm on."

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I wasn’t aware that the wallet address is not the public key itself, but a hash of it. While this means that a coin cannot be easily stolen before being spent, double spending attacks may still be possible. I feel the statement „security of the signature scheme is irrelevant if addresses are only used once“ is too blunt. One would have to analyze more carefully what consequences this would have in practice.

Comment: How would double spending be possible?

Comment: suppose someone transfers a coin. now the public key is known to everybody. because the signature scheme is broken, anyone can now quickly issue a transaction of the coin to his account and hope that the network accepts it before the "original" transaction.

Comment: @mti I see your logic. But as an attacker you would need to receive the transaction, and then produce a malicious one and post it to the network faster than the original transaction reaching the majority of miners (which takes seconds). I agree if you assume that the attacker can get some time advantage, e.g. by controlling outgoing network traffic of the victim. But then you have a range of other vulnerabilities as well.

Comment: The question does not mention Bitcoin or any other crypto currency, so this discussion is probably off-topic. Also, the protocol discussion would be a better fit for other SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10377) talks about that. From what I can understand although difficult in theory an attack can be used to retrieve the private key and spend all the coins if the used signature scheme is based on elliptic curve cryptography (as in bitcoin). Also advances in quantum computing can arrive a lot faster than expected so btc devs should start working on using lattice-based crypto.